# How to sum up the power and time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary data in which it is in form of dictionary within dictionary

{

```
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 10, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 20, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 43, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 11, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 14, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 21, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 15, 09, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 15, 12, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 15, 40, 27)}
```

}

How to do I sum the data of both column based on hourly

I want to do like this -- Taking first hour

```
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 10, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 20, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 43, 27)},
```

**Sum of pw    :** 0.12345 + 0.12345 + 0.12345

**Sum of start :** datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 10, 27) + datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 20, 27) + datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 43, 27)

**Next sum  I need to do this**

```
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 11, 27)},
{pw : 0.12345 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 14, 27)}
```

**Sum of pw :** 0.12345 + 0.12345
**Sum of start :** datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 11, 27) + datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 14, 27)

**More details on :** `datatime.datetime( YYYY , MM , DD , HH , MM , SS )`

**Final output**

```
0.3735 , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 10, 27) + datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 20, 27) + datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 43, 27)
0.249  , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 11, 27) + datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 14, 27)
0.498  , ....
```

Start and End of date time

```
        Start                                             End 
datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 10, 27) , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 13, 43, 27)
    
datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 11, 27) , datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 14, 14, 27)
    
datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 15, 03, 27) ,  datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 14, 15, 40, 27)
```

Comment: So only difference is hour, so working `df.groupby('start')['pw'].sum()` ? Or need `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='start', freq='H'))['pw'].sum()` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the question can you check. I want to sum `pw` and `datetime`

Comment: @jezrael :  I am trying how to add add date time

Comment: @jezrael : I have added output .. But unable to calculate the date time .. checking how to sum HH , MM , SS

Comment: `But unable to calculate the date time` - Yop, it is impossible.

Comment: @jezrael : I am using this to calculate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988281/how-to-add-two-datetime-datetime-objects

Comment: Do you read first sentence? `Agreeing with the previous poster, there isn't a meaningful way to add two datetimes`

Comment: @jezrael : Can check from your end as well how to sum up

Comment: hmmm, I have data in question only. So can you change input data with `end` datetimes and add expected output?

Comment: @jezrael : I have added start and end time may be this will help you to calculate the sum

Comment: I ma confused more, it belongs to input data? Is possible remove part of question for add datetimes (what is impossible) ? And add expected ouput?

Comment: I understand what is grouping by hour, but no idea how is converted datetimes, because sum not possible.

Comment: @jezrael : At least based on datetime can you calculate sum of pw. That is also fine for me

Comment: try `df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='start', freq='H'))['pw'].sum().reset_index()`